# How to combine DiagrammeR with other plots in one panel?

Tags: r, plot, panel, gridextra, diagrammer

I would like to include a diagram from DiagrammeR in a multipanel plot for example from ggplot2, but unfortunately DiagrammeR does not write on the graphic device. Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is my example, which works fine with two ggplot2 graphs, but not when  I combine it with DiagrammeR.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
y <- x*rnorm(n=10, mean = 1, sd = 0.2)
data <- data.frame(x,y)
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
plot1 <- arrangeGrob(plot, top = textGrob("A", x = unit(0.0, "npc"), y =   
unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"), gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=14, 
fontfamily="Times")))
plot2 <- arrangeGrob(plot, top = textGrob("B", x = unit(0.0, "npc"), y =   
unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"), gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=14, 
fontfamily="Times")))
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2)

d <- grViz("

    digraph boxes_and_circles {

    # add node statements
    node [shape = box]
    A; B

    node [shape = box]
    C; D

    A->C; B->D

}

")

d
d <- arrangeGrob(d, top = textGrob("B", x = unit(0.0, "npc"), y = unit(1, 
"npc"), just=c("left","top"), gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=14,
fontfamily="Times")))
grid.arrange(plot1, d)
```

Comment: This is the only thing I have found during my internet search, but sadly it is far from beeing optimal: [link] (https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/126)